# How to convert between coordinates when subView frame outside the parent frame?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, ios9, frame

I have these three views:

1. grandView
2. parentView
3. childView

this how they are ordered:

```
grandView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)

//add parent view
parentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-100,grandView.frame.width,200)
grandView.addSubView(parentView)

//add child view
childView = CGRectMake(0,150,grandView.frame.width,20)
parentView.addSubView(childView)
```

I want to add childView to grandView, without changing it's position, so first thing i need to change the frame to be in grandView coordinates, and then add subView, here is what i did:

```
childView.frame = parentView.convertRect(childView.frame, toView: grandView)
grandView.addSubView(childView)
```

but that's doesn't work , i think because the parentView frame is outside grandView frame. How to solve it ?

**EDIT:**

please note that:

- `grandView is the controller.view` .
- the above code work correctly just if i call it after viewDidAppear has been called. I am not sure why ?

Comment: The conversion should work, try debug the assignment to `childView.frame`

Comment: all your adding subviews or in which method ? , view did load or some other method.